# Autoload parent class from a different directory

Tags: php, oop, autoload

I´m having a hard time trying to autoload parent classes

this is my directory structure

```
controllers
--- Homepage.php
core
--- Controller.php
index.php
```

This is the content of my index.php

```
function __autoload($class_name)
{
    $file_name = str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class_name) . '.php';
    include $file_name;
}

$homepage = new \Controllers\Homepage();
$homepage->index();
```

This is the content of my controllers/Homepage.php file

```
namespace Controllers;

class Homepage extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Homepage::index';
    }

}
```

and this is my core/Controller.php

```
namespace Core;

class Controller
{

    protected function something()
    {
        echo 'blablabla';
    }

}
```

when i run index.php the autoloader loads Hompege correctly but is looking for Controller.php in the controllers directory I tried extending from class Homepage extends Core\Controller but now is trying to get it from controllers/core

Comment: What happen if you put `use \Core\Controller;` after the namespace declaration in Homepage.php ?

Comment: tried that too but it returns Parse error: parse error, expecting `"identifier (T_STRING)"'

Comment: Or `extends \Core\Controller`

Comment: It is a long time ago, but I think the problem should be solved by adding  `use Core\Controller;` within controllers/Homepage.php should do the job (as frz3993 commented). The error looks like you did it the wrong way. Try it again - it should be the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the namespaces are resolved:

1. `class Homepage extends Controller`

   `Controller` is resolved to `Controller\Controller` because it is a non-qualified class name (like a relative file path), and the current namespace is used.
2. `class Homepage extends Core\Controller`

   `Core/Controller` is resolved to `Controller\Core\Controller` because it also is a non-qualified class name and a sub-namespace of the current namespace is used
3. `class Homepage extends \Core\Controller`

   `\Core\Controller` is a fully qualified class name and will be resolved to `Core\Controller`
4. `use Core\Controller; class Homepage extends Controller`

   Here the `use` statement specifies that a non-qualified `Controller` is treated as `Core\Controller`

**Variants 3 and 4 will work as intended.**